# Finding The Sum OF Two Values In SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `Usage` and it contains the following columns

```
sl_No 
usage_ID 
energyItem_ID 
qty 
unit_ID 
location_ID
p_Rate
```

Sometimes the same `EnergyItem` might be located at different locations..

During those conditions how can I get the sum of qty of an individual `energyItem`..

How to get the sum of the qty of `energyItems`?

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood correctly, you're trying to find the quantity of each 
energy item, regardless of its location, using information in a single table.

The following query will give you the energyItem_ID of each item followed by the total quantity of each item:

```
SELECT energyItem_ID,Sum(qty) as TotalQuantity
FROM Usage
GROUP BY energyItem_ID
ORDER BY energyItem_ID
```

If, on the other hand, you wanted the quantity of each energy item, broken down by location, you would need the following:

```
SELECT location_ID,energyItemID,Sum(qty) as QuantityByLocation
FROM Usage
GROUP BY location_ID,energyItemID
ORDER BY location_ID,energyItemID
```

The order by clauses make the result easier to follow, but are not strictly necessary.

Finally, the answer by marc_s will give you the quantity of a specific energyItem.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT EnergyItem_ID, SUM(qty)
FROM dbo.Usage
WHERE EnergyItem_ID = 42  -- or whatever ....
GROUP BY EnergyItem_ID
```

Or what are you looking for?? The question isn't very clear on the expected output....

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.usage_ID , b.sum(p_Rate) as total from Table_1 a 
inner join Table_2  as b on a.usage_ID = b.usage_ID 
group by a.usage_ID
```